# how to export modules that requires other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a node js project that is getting bigger and bigger, and I'm trying to tidy up my code. This is just a case example.

this is my index.js:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', () => doSomething())
})

http.listen(4000, () => console.log('server started'))
```

and I'd like to import doSomething from another file (say functions.js) like this:

```js
function doSomething(){
  console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
}

module.exports =  { doSomething }
```

modifying index.js as follows:

```js
[...]
const library = require('./functions.js')
[...]
socket.on('message', () => library.doSomething())
```

but of course:
`io is not defined` in functions.js.

**QUESTION:**
How could I import the required modules so that they are shared in both files?

Comment: What is the problem with `require('socket.io')` in `functions.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `function.js` file as below:

```
function doSomething(){
  let self = this;
  console.log(self.io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
}

module.exports = function (io) {
  let self = this;
  self.io = io;
  return {
    doSomething: doSomething.bind(self)
  };
};
```

And its usage in `index.js` file will be:

```
const Library = require('./functions.js');
const library = Library(io);

socket.on('message', () => library.doSomething())
```

Comment: your answer looks very elegant, but I'm getting an error calling the `self.io = io` statement because self is `undefined`...I'm declaring `Library` and `library` right after the io declaration

Comment: `self` equals to `this` and in the first state, `this = {}`, so It can't be undefined. Can you show me your code? @ddgg

Comment: I got it! I was compiling functions.js in `strict mode` hence `this` was undefined. I don't need to `use strict` so I guess my problme is SOLVED. Thank you very much!.

Comment: It would be interesting anyway for me to understand how would you overcome the issue. As I was logging `this` using your code I was getting the instance of what-it-look-to-me-as-the whole application...would you initialize `this` as an empty object? Thank you again!

Comment: I dont' understand your question. what you mean ` instance of what-it-look-to-me-as-the whole application`?? @ddgg

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the required packages in your `functions.js`.

Your `functions.js` should be something like

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
//Include other packages here
function doSomething(){
  console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
}

//Other functions here

//Export all that you need to be exported
module.exports =  { doSomething }
```